# Which Intel virtualizaton techniques are necessary for Docker?

Tags: virtualization

Which Intel virtualizaton techniques are necessary for Docker?

On a Linux system running on a Intel cpu, what Virtualization Technologies by Intel are necessary to fullfill the execution of a Docker container? E.g. there are VT-X, ...

Or is there no need of using such a technology because Docker is somehow different to existing virtualization solutions like VirtualBox. In this case, why is there no need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run Docker directly on a non VT-X machine (no Virtual Machine used)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198189/can-i-run-docker-directly-on-a-non-vt-x-machine-no-virtual-machine-used)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory" even though it's enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441382/error-with-pre-create-check-this-computer-doesnt-have-vt-x-amd-v-enabled-ena)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. Docker uses a completely different system - it's not running a virtual machine so much as a super chroot. See the question below:
[Can I run Docker directly on a non VT-X machine (no Virtual Machine used)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198189/can-i-run-docker-directly-on-a-non-vt-x-machine-no-virtual-machine-used)

The tutorials that tell you you'll need VT-x are usually based on running docker in Windows (on Hyper-V) or in VirtualBox.