# Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory" even though it's enabled

Tags: docker, devops

Running docker toolbox ( [v19.03.1](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v19.03.1))  from Windows 10 Home edition yields the following error message:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...
```

I tried a lot of help threads online, but all of them boils down to enabling AMD-V (or intel equivalent) in the BIOS (done), disabling Hyper-V (can't, Home edition doesn't even have it), disabling hypervisorlaunchtype (done) or disabling core isolation (it's off) and it still doesn't work. Here are some screenshots to show some of my settings.

Running a Ryzen 3600 with x570 board, I enabled virtualization in the BIOS:

Here is my bcdedit, hypervisorlaunchtype is Off.

Windows features: I tried all permutation of turning on and off virtual machine platform / windows hypervisor platform, none of them worked, this is the current state.

Core isolation off.

All settings in one image: [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AcO0.png)

I also tried disabling anti-virus, it didn't help. Tried reinstalling docker toolbox, VirtualBox, together, separately, didn't work. (tried VirtualBox versions `5.2.20` (included in docker toolbox installer) and the newest `6.0.10` version)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update:**
I successfully installed Ubuntu 18 (64 bit) in VirtualBox, so I assume my virtualization is perfectly fine, so the problem must be with Docker.

Comment: any reason you didn't go docker for windows?https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Comment: Windows 10 Home doesn't support Hyper-V and didn't want to change to Pro.

Comment: I see :( This here suggests making your PC really reboot https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722/2. other than that I'm no help

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately, it didn't work, I also successfully installed a 64 bit Ubuntu 18 in VirtualBox, so my virtualization is fine, the problem is with Docker.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I just faced same issue on Windows 10 Home with Docker Toolbox 18.09.3 (laptop powered by Ryzen 2500U): running normal linux image via Virtualbox works like a charm, and `msinfo32` tool reports "virtualization enabled: true"

What helped me was adding `--virtualbox-no-vtx-check` to the `docker-machine create` command, to be more specific I used this cmd:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 \
    --virtualbox-cpu-count=4 --virtualbox-disk-size=40960 \
    --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default
```

And everything worked just great! Hope this helps on your case as well :-)

Answer (score 16):

Simply, bypass Virtualization check in the Docker Quickstart Terminal shell script. Follow below steps:

1. Go to C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox.
2. Edit start.sh file in a text editor (preferably, select run as administrator)
3. Update line #69 (add `--virtualbox-no-vtx-check`) as `"${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check $PROXY_ENV "${VM}"`
4. Save and close the file.
5. Click on "Docker Quickstart Terminal" on the desktop, after restarting your machine.

Docker should be up and running in your Windows machine without any issues.

~Note: If you face any error with VirtualBox, try to uninstall VirtualBox and install latest version and try again.

Answer (score 12):

to make it more clear, I was helped by these commands in cmd (win + r):

```
  docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096
```

then:

```
  docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked updating `c:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe` file from here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ci-cd/docker-machine (you have to do it as Administrator and accept UAC warning) and restarting Docker Console (Docker V M was created successfully).